# is there any way to open React native Screen from React native WebView

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have React JS website which display in react native Webview. now i want to pass that website result to react native screen and want to navigate from that website to react native screen.

```
 <WebView
    style={{flex: 1,marginTop: Constants.statusBarHeight}}
    source={{ uri: url }}
     originWhitelist={['*']}
       javaScriptEnabled={true} 
       startInLoadingState={true}
       scalesPageToFit={true}
       domStorageEnabled={true}
        
  />
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `postMessage` from `WebView` to communicate with `Native`.

```
const html = `
  <html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <script>
      setTimeout(function () {
        window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage("Hello!")
      }, 2000)
    </script>
  </body>
  </html>
`;

<WebView
  source={{ html }}
  onMessage={(event) => {
    alert(event.nativeEvent.data);
  }}
/>
```

See [Communicating between JS and Native](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Guide.md#communicating-between-js-and-native) for details.